# How to get count of records satisfying multipel critierias in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an sql table with the below columns
OrderNo, GroupNum, ShipMethod, TrackingNo

I want to find number of orders that have multiple 'ShipMethod' for same groupnum?

Sample records wourld be:

```
Order123    1     DHL
Order123    2     DHL1
Order123    2     Fedex
```

Then i need to get result stating 2 or if possible output as below:

```
OrderNumer  GroupNum    Count
----------  -------     -----
Order123      2         2 (Because 2 shipmethods)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Group by the columns you want to be unique, use `count()` to get each groups count and use `having` to limit the output to only the relevant groups

```
select ordernum, groupnum, count(*) as cnt
from your_table
group by ordernum, groupnum
having count(*) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly:

```
select OrderNumer, groupnum, count(*)
from t
group by OrderNumer, groupnum
having count(*) > 1;
```

You may also want `count(distinct shipmethod)`, if you want to count the distinct values rather than the number of rows.